# last version of NodeJS install by apt-get

Tags: node.js, webserver, apt-get

Debian Linux (Debian Stable, UBUNTU LTS, etc.) and others use `apt-get`  as good and reliable installer tool. I need to use *only `apt-get`*... The problem is that I do the simple

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

but as result I have `nodejs --version` (or `node --version`)

```
 0.10.41
```

(!) It is not the today's [most updated stable Node.JS version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js),

```
 5.2.0
```

I also try `node -p process.versions.v8` that results in

```
  3.14.5.9
```

so, also is very less than **5.2**.

---

### NOTES

I am using UBUNTU 14 LTS.... And try a workaround but not works,

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
 sudo apt-get remove --purge node  #enforce any lapse
```

And, as [this suggestion](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/)

```
 curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
 sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

not works, some results.

Answer (score 4):

When installing from nodesource, you need to specify which version you want to install.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_iojs_3.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_iojs_2.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_iojs_1.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo -E bash -
```

Followed by

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` (or `sudo apt-get install -y iojs` for iojs)

When using the url without any version (as you did), it seems you get node 0.10 for some reason.

You'll find [more information here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

Comment: Thanks! You show many `curl` commands, but I need only the first... And any other I whant to remove... What the ppa-name of them? (how to remove the wrong PPA with `sudo ppa-purge nodeJS`?? nodeJS PPA not exist, what the real name?)

Comment: Hello?  Well it works fine (!) even without a `ppa-purge` of old versions... But, please explain *how to purge from PPA the old versions* (purge the `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_Y.x` that I do by accident or not in use).