# how to install npm after purge

Tags: ubuntu, npm, apt-get

As I [need an updated version of NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34243112/287948), I first remove old version... By:

```
 apt-get remove --purge nodejs
 apt-get remove --purge node
 apt-get autoremove
```

... [after sucess on install last version of NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243286/287948), I ran the npm install procedure,

```
 node --version  # now is ok!
 sudo apt-get install npm  # ERROR!!!!
```

So, **how to install *npm* in this context** (after this purge process)

EDIT:

PS: as I show by link above and inline-comment above, `nodejs --version` is OK, is good, no problem. This question was about `npm` and `apt-get`... And now I see [that part of the answer is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/462344/439867).

---

The error messages, [same as this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/462337/439867)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) 
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       ...
       Depends: ... but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

... Nobody say, but the problem is not with my NodeJS or my UBUNTU, the problem is like a bug with `sudo apt-get install npm`, **this command is with a bug**: need to fix the message.

As [sayd here in similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/462344/439867), the `npm`  was installed by the modern NodeJS's installation (!!), so apt-get must say "ok, no problem, you have a good and updated `npm`".

Conclusion:

1. use only "`curl + apt`" commands with the correct `setup_N.x` choice, as illustred in all links posted here.  The installation of `nodejs`  will install also `npm`.
2. not use `apt-get install npm`, avoid it. Is a bug.

---

**NOTE**: a typical "`curl + apt`"  is

```
 curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and, after sucess with this install procedure, to check `npm` existence, use

```
  npm --version
```

so, if shows a version number (like 3.3.12), **`npm` was installed!**

**IMPORTANT**: to update `npm` (ex. from 3.3.12 to 3.5.2)  *not use `apt-get`* (!), use the `npm` itself,

```
 sudo npm install npm -g
```

---

---

### EDIT 2017

Today, 2017, at UBUNTU 16 LTS, is possible... And using only `atp` (is most  friendly tham `apt-get`):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs  # need it first!
sudo apt install npm
```

... But ...it is the "most updated version of the sluggish LTS",  ... check each version (!)...

Step-by-step **for a specific version choice** (v6.x as illustration), as [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04):

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh`
2. `sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh`
3. `atp install nodejs`

Answer (score 2):

Remove nodejs and fix broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs node npm
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Install nodejs using a PPA

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Create a symbolic link for node, as many Node.js tools use this name to execute.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks,  all is working (`nodejs`, `node`  etc.) as I show by links (and is not node 4.X is node 5.X) ... And, as I see with more atention [at the similar erro link](http://askubuntu.com/q/462337/439867), there are no problem with my `npm`, it was there (!!)... The problem is with UBUNTU that say nothing about in the `apt-get` wrong: now `npm` is installed with  `nodejs`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` is very dangerous I guess